# Can not make swipe gesture work

Tags: xamarin.ios

I've tried to make swipe gesture for user swipe to left and right.

Fortunately, I found a useful example in Professional iPhone Programming with MonoTouch and .NET/C# chapter page 292 Recognizing Gestures and this article.
However, when I run this code in simulator, nothing happens. What did is I miss?

Please could you help me to make this work?

The code that I used can be downloaded by the following link. http://www.7749tutor.com/code/iPad06.zip
Please, have a look at line 31 of MyViewController.cs file

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I do it in one of my views:

(inside my class definition)

```cs
public static Selector RightSwipeSelector
{
    get
    {
        return new Selector("HandleRightSwipe");
    }
}

public class SwipeRecogniserDelegate : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    public override bool ShouldReceiveTouch (UIGestureRecognizer recognizer, UITouch touch)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

[Export("HandleRightSwipe")]
public void HandleRightSwipe(UISwipeGestureRecognizer recogniser)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Got a right swipe.");
}
```

(inside ViewDidLoad)

```cs
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer sgrRight=new UISwipeGestureRecognizer();

    sgrRight.AddTarget(this,RightSwipeSelector);

    sgrRight.Direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;

    sgrRight.Delegate=new SwipeRecogniserDelegate();

    View.AddGestureRecognizer(sgrRight);
```

Comment: I follow your suggestion and put it to new project. Unfortunately, it doesn't work and get error. Please this link to download source file. http://cid-cb0e519ed38c0ab2.office.live.com/self.aspx/Code/EbookReader.zip

Comment: OK I had to do two things to make that work in your solution. First of all, you need a reference to MainComicsViewController outside of FinishedLaunching() - otherwise the garbage collector gets rid of your view and you get an exception and/or debugger crash when you try the swipe. Secondly, the HandleRightSwipe method and the RightSwipeSelector property should both be defined in the MainComicsViewController class. I made those two changes, and the gesture is now working.

Comment: Thank a lot vlad. That work as I expected. 
I did it with your suggestion and put new working source file. http://cid-cb0e519ed38c0ab2.office.live.com/self.aspx/Code/EbookReader.zip Hope someone may find this useful.

Comment: Very helpful. But is it still this complicated with the latest MonoTouch? Very leaky abstraction..

Comment: As far as I know this hasn't been changed by 5.2.10.

Comment: Added another answer that makes it easier to do swipes.

Answer (score 8):

I made this much easier class extension method to a UIView instance: [View Extension](https://gist.github.com/2884348)

You use it like:

```
View.Swipe(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right).Event += (s, r) =>
    new UIAlertView("Swipe Test", "Swipe " + r.Direction.ToString(), null, "Ok")
        .Show();
```

No longer do you have to add ugly code to your projects for swipes!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chuck Savage :)